# How to get nested key in firebase real time database

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am creating a database for the products. The products are pushed into the database successfully but I am facing a problem in getting the data because the keys are nested. How can I target the nested key?
Please help me.

Using the below code I am getting my all the products data of currently logged in user.

```
    useEffect(() => {
    const getProductsData = async () => {
        const userId = await AsyncStorage.getItem('uid')
        database()
            .ref(`Products/${userId}`)
            .on('value', data => {
                console.log(data.val())
            });

    }
    getProductsData()
}, [])
```

[**console of the data.val()**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sPtSg.png)

[image: Firebase database heirarchy]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your `userId` is the `dUD7M...` value in the screenshot you shared, the data snapshot you get will contain the data for both child nodes in that screenshot. You can loop over those children with:

```
const userId = await AsyncStorage.getItem('uid')
database()
    .ref(`Products/${userId}`)
    .on('value', snapshot => {
        snapshot.forEach((data) => { // 
            console.log(data.val())
        });
    });
```

Comment: Thank you @Frank van Puffelen for the solution. I don't know that I can iterate on it directly. I was trying Object.Keys and Object.entries.